# React native project deleted on xcode, can't run "run-ios react-native"

Tags: xcode, react-native, frontend, project

I've deleted my React native project while trying to make Google maps work on Xcode being .xcodeproje and .xcworkspace. Which means I am unable to run IOS simulator.

I've tried deleting Xcode and reinstalling but it doesn't find the react native project on Xcode. Tried linking the files and creating another project but no result. It gives the error below when I try building the simulator. The files that were in the deleted file are in my VS Codde within the ios file.

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone7"
error Could not find Xcode project files in "ios" folder. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: which files are gone?

Comment: PROJECT_NAME.xcworkspace .  and   PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproje .

Comment: If you don't need expo just run $ npm run eject

Comment: I need @expo vector icons on VS code

Comment: would this work? https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

Comment: I would rather keep the style I found there. Why? is it necessary to eject it to reintegrate the project in Xcode? Is there no other way? Before deleting it I had all the files I needed even with expo on. It would be a shame if i need to eject it because of a mess up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your react-native project to restore your deleted files.

**1 - Delete your ios and android folder**

**2 - In your project directory:**

```
react-native upgrade
```

**3 - link for any native dependency:**

```
react-native link
```

**4 - And after that:**

```
react-native run-ios
```

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: I've done as you said, it did create another IOS andAndrois folder. when I react-native run-ios the emulator shows but the build failed and the project is not present in the emulator. Can we skype this throught

Comment: So this problem has been solved. you have another problem now. The deleted files have been restored. please mark my answer and +1, then ask another question with the new error/log.

Comment: You really just want the credit don't you, it doesn't matter if the situation is half baked. I will just mark your answer in this case since that it was made it work

Comment: No bro, you are wrong. This is the rules of stackoverflow. It's better to ask a new question about another problem. ask the question. We are here to have a unique answer for each question. <3

Comment: Well then if so, I have opened a new case, you are welcomed to emphasize on your statement here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202543/react-native-project-not-on-present-ios-simulator-or-on-xcode

Comment: Ok. Sure brother