# React native project not on present IOS simulator or on Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, frontend, project

this is the second part of a bigger problem where the first part was solved here [React native project deleted on xcode, can't run "run-ios react-native"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194342/react-native-project-deleted-on-xcode-cant-run-run-ios-react-native/56196699?noredirect=1#comment99027330_56196699).

I have deleted my project on Xcode may it be .xcworkspace or .xcodeproje.

Because of that, I had to delete IOS and android folders while downgrading, updating and re-upgrading my react version to re-install IOS and android folders.

Thanks to that the emulator is working but unfortunately the project isn't present in the emulator and is still absent with Xcode. One thing to point out is that the simulator only appears when ran in the integrated terminal and nor in general terminal after cd-ing in the project folder.

Can anyone please help re-integrating the project in the emulator and on Xcode please.

Here is the error when the emulator is running in a general terminal:

```
error Command failed: xcrun instruments -s
xcrun: error: Failed to determine realpath of '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk' (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Here is the error for building the project within emulator when ran from VS code integrated terminal:

> error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening project.xcodeproj

Comment: Check my updated answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, select Xcode menu, then Preferences, then Locations tab. Click on the advanced button, select legacy and exit Xcode.